# Leaflet map tilelayer does not load in correctly

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I'm trying to add a leaflet map to a website I am making for an assignment, but the tilelayer loads in in different pieces, cutting certain pieces off.
[snippet of the confused map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNFjq.png)

I've tried to change some of the variables to make it fit better, and the closest I've come is by putting the tilesize on 800. But when I change the tilesize, the coordinates no longer match up to the map.

Javascript of the map (copied from the tutorial with minor changes)

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibGVjdG9yd291dGVyIiwiYSI6ImNrM25qZWs1dTB4NHgza240bW0zOG1qZngifQ.1uF5JjJA8l5SpTW3NVQJJQ'
}).addTo(map);
```

html:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
    crossorigin="" defer ></script>
    <script src="js/cafmmap.js" defer></script>
<!-- unrelated html stuff -->
        <section class="detailItem">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </section>
```

My css just has a "height: 100%;" applied to the map

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/R4BkXbup0u67HHVi)